# Firebase storage: Unable to download files uploaded via Ruby API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm using the google-cloud-storage service to upload and download files from my Ruby on Rails app to Firebase storage (part of another app I'm interfacing with).

Uploading works perfectly, using the JSON key from the Firebase service accounts section. I'm uploading files like this:

```
STORAGE = Google::Cloud::Storage.new(
    project_id: "blah",
    credentials: File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'firebase-auth.json')
)

BUCKET = STORAGE.bucket DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID

...

file_on_firebase = BUCKET.create_file(file_path.to_s, firebase_path, acl: "public_read")
```

I can see the uploaded files in the Firebase storage console, but when I try to download them via the console I get the following error in my browser's console:

```
uncaught exception: CustomError: Error in protected function: Firebase Storage: 
User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
```

This is strange because the account I'm accessing Firebase console with is the main service account, and I can download other (manually uploaded) files no problem. The only ones I have trouble downloading are the ones uploaded from my Rails app.

Any thoughts? I'm thinking it must have to do with setting the `acl` attribute of the `file` to `public_read`. Not sure why that would prevent downloading the file from the console, however. It seems like I can access files OK using their `public_url`.

Comment: I did some quick checking around and the only thing I could think of was that maybe that user doesn't have correct IAM permissions for that particular bucket/folder for some reason.  Have you checked those at all?

Comment: The account I'm logged in to Firebase console with is marked as "Owner" of the project. It's not marked as a service account, however. Maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you change your storage rules? Enter to Storage and after to rules in Firebase Console (web) and look your rules.

If you have this:

```
allow read: if request.auth != null;
```

Means users should be authenticated for read the file.

Use this for more security rules practices.

Comment: It looks like my rules are set to allow read even w/o auth:
      `allow read;`
      `allow write: if request.auth != null;`

Comment: Your rules say the User should be authenticated for read the file. Try to change the rules from  "if request.auth != null" to "if request.auth === null"